# Combing very small hair curves with collision enabled

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, sculpting, hair, collision

When trying to comb hair curves I noticed that the `Use Sculpt Collision` option does not work properly for very small hairs.

The following spheres have hair curves with 3mm, 3cm and 3dm of length attached to them. All curves have 5 control points. The goal with all spheres was to "comb down" the strands of hair.

[image]

Only the hair on the last sphere behaves as desired.

I suspect that this behavior has something to do with the resolution of the real-time collision since scaling up and applying the new scale improves this issue for the leftmost sphere.

[image]

Even at 100x size not all hairs conform nicely to the surface of the sphere.

Are there any global physics-settings that can improve this behavior?

Comment: you could use a Geometry Nodes modifier to move up the control points that are below the surface. Here is an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290837/107598